# cabal build error `gcc` failed: connot find `#include`

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I try to build `qhull` from hackage and get the error

```
fatal error: qhull_ra.h: No such file or directory
        2 | #include "qhull_ra.h"

`gcc' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
```

The file is in the `Cdir` and the relevant parts of the cabal file are

```
  include-dirs:        ./Cdir
  C-sources:           ./Cdir/libqhull_r.c
                     , ./Cdir/geom_r.c
                     , ...
```

The file `qhull_ra.h` is not listed as C-sources, because it is a header file.

I did not write the code and are not experienced with including C code into haskell packages. The failure occurs sometimes and sometimes not, but I cannot tell when. What is wrong? I want to upload the package (authorized by the author); what do I have to change to make it compile with `cabal install`?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that `cabal install` is (since recently) much more strict than `cabal build` when looking for files. So, I believe here the problem is that your include files are not being picked up by cabal.

I think you can fix that by listing your header files in a [`includes:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-includes) field. So at least:

```
   include-dirs: Cdir
   includes:     qhull_ra.h
   c-sources:    Cdir/libqhull_r.c
               , ...
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try. It would be nice, if restrictiosn of the sort would be clearly communicated! What confuses me, however, is that the error does not always happen and occurs at local (not hackage uploaded versions) as well. I fear it is related to some caching of cabal; it seems to happen using stack or cabal to build.

Comment: It's not **includes**, it's **install-includes**. cc @user855443

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent my understanding is that install-includes means all packages that depend on your package can also use your header file. I don't believe that is necessary in this case.

Comment: I've just uploaded a package to Hackage. Does not work with **includes**. Works with **install-includes**.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that sounds like a bug in cabal or a mistake in the documentation, as it says: "Note that in order for files listed in install-includes to be usable when compiling the package itself, they need to be listed in the includes field as well."

Comment: That's not my understanding from the doc here: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-install-includes

Comment: Ah yes, the sentence you mention is at the bottom. Strange. But I swear I proceeded as I said above.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - I tried to `install-includes` all the c header file, but it failed again. The error is not enlightening, see `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/qhull-0.1.0.4/reports/2`. should I include all the c headers in `includes` as well? The package compiles locally (most of the time).

Comment: @user855443 That does not seem to be related to the C files. This is the built of an exe file which fails (**test_convexhull**). You could remove it.